# Find the limit of $\frac{1}{n^2-\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I was trying to solve the following task but I stumbled across something I do not understand:

Calculate:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2-\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}}$$

my attempt was to factorize n^2 out of the squareroot:

$$$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2-\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}}$$

\begin{align}
\\a_n & = \frac{1}{n^2-\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}} \\
 & =\frac{1}{n^2-\sqrt{n^4\left(1+\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)}} \\
 & =\frac{1}{n^2-n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}}} \\  
\end{align}

Therefor, I thought that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2-n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}}}$$
$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\left(n^2-n^2\right)\sqrt{1}} = \infty$$

I also tried a different way where I got to the result of  $-\dfrac{1}{2}$.
I am not going to show that method here but it starts with using the 3rd binomial formula. Then, having the squareroot at the top of the fraction, I factorized $n^2$ and it all worked.

Why does this method like shown above not work?

I am very happy for any help.

P.S. This is not the only example where this kind of getting to a solution does not work for me. Are there cases where I am not allowed to factorize something?

Comment: Why did you suddenly decide the answer was $\infty$? That seemed to come from nowhere.

Comment: Multiply and divide the fraction by the conjugate of denominator and you will see that the answer is not $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Use

$$\frac{1}{n^2-\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}}\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}}{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}}=\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}}{-4n^2-n}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4/n^2+1/n^3}}{-4-1/n}$$

In your attempt the following

$$n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}}=n^2\cdot \sqrt1$$

is uncorrect, indeed by binomial series expansion

$$\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}}=1+\frac{2}{n^2}+o(1/n^2)$$

from here you can conclude by your attempt.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did after that. I am just interested in why what I did, does not work.

Comment: @FinnEggers Ok I'll give a look!

Comment: Oh okay I see my mistake! I thought everything under the squareroot evaluates to 1 but it doesn't seem to be that easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$ (n^2 + 2)^2 < n^4 + 4 n^2 + n < \left(n^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{2n} \right)^2  $$
$$ n^2 + 2 < \sqrt{n^4 + 4 n^2 + n \;} \; < \; n^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{2n}   $$
$$ - 2 > n^2 -\sqrt{n^4 + 4 n^2 + n \;} \; > \; - 2 - \frac{1}{2n}   $$
$$ - \frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{n^2 -\sqrt{n^4 + 4 n^2 + n \;} } \; < \; - \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{2n}}   $$
these are for $n > 4$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** There's a standard trick here called "multiplying by the conjugate": Multiply both the numerator and denominator of
$$\frac{1}{a + \sqrt{b}}$$
by $a - \sqrt{b}$, which rationalizes the latter. Often limit problems like these are arranged so that doing so leads to a convenient cancellation.

Comment: Well thats exactly what I did after that. But why does my way not work?

Answer (score 2):

You nearly had the answer yourself: In the line

$$\begin{align}
\\a_n & = \frac{1}{n^2-\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}} \\
 & =\frac{1}{n^2-\sqrt{n^4\left(1+\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)}} \\
 & =\frac{1}{n^2-n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}}} \\  
\end{align}$$
For large $n$ $$\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}}  \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2} (\frac{4}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3})$$ and $n^2$ this gives
$$\approx n^2 + \frac{1}{2} (4+\frac{1}{n})$$ so that the final result is
$$\frac{1}{n^2-n^2-2-\frac{1}{2 n}}$$ from which you can determine the desired result.

Comment: Could you briefly explain the rule you used to cancel out the sqrt?

Comment: I expanded the square root by the binomial expansion, $\sqrt{1 + x} \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2}x$ for small $x$. Then expansion of $n^2 \times$ the square root gives the term $n^2 \times (1 + \frac{1}{2} x )= n^2 + n^2 \frac{1}{2}x $

Answer (score 1):

write it as $$\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+4n^2+n}}{n^4-n^4-4n^2-n}$$ and this is $$\frac{n^2(1+\sqrt{1+1/n^2+1/n^3})}{n^2(-4-1/n^2)}$$